# Program to find determinant not working

Tags: c, matrix

So I am trying to write a program to find determinant of a n*n matrix. This is what I have written:

```
int a[10][10],b[10][10],o;
main()
{
    int i,j;
    printf("Enter Order: ");scanf("%d",&o);
    printf("Enter Matrix:\n");
    for(i=1;i<=o;i++)
    {
        for(j=1;j<=o;j++)
            scanf("%d",&a[i][j]);
    }
    printf("The determinant is %d",det(a,o));
    printf("\n");
}
int det(int t[10][10],int ord)
{
    int d=0,i,j;
    if(ord==2)
    {
        d=(t[1][1]*t[2][2])-(t[2][1]*t[1][2]);
    }
    else if(ord>2)
    {
        for(i=1;i<=ord;i++)
        {
            d=d+(t[1][i]*cofac(t,ord,1,i))
        }
    }

    return d;
}
int cofac(int t[10][10],int ord,int row,int col)
{
    int i=1,j=0,x,y;
    for(x=1;x<=ord;x++)
    {
        for(y=1;y<=ord;y++)
        {
            if(x!=row && y!=col)
            {
                j++;
                b[i][j]=a[x][y];
            }
        }
        if(j==ord-1)
        {
            i++;j=0;
        }
    }
    return((pow(-1,row+col))*det(b,ord-1));
}
```

Now for some reason, this works fine for 3*3 matrices but gives the wrong answer for higher order matrices. Could someone explain to me why? I have been trying to solve this for hours but just couldn't understand what is happening.

Comment: `i<=o` is an ugly idea, since `o` looks like `0`. It hinders code readability.

Comment: This is an excellent occasion to learn how to use a debugger.

Comment: You can easily avoid `pow` using `int val = det(b,ord-1); if (((row+col)%2) == 1) val *= -1; return val;`... In other words checking if the exponent is odd.

Comment: Using a *global* array `b` as intermediate storage during the `det`/`cofac` recursion will probably not work.

Comment: Another way to avoid `pow` is to have `cofac`'s caller calculate the sign. It just needs to flip the sign for each iteration of the loop.

Comment: the posted code does not compile!  1) it is missing the necessary `#include` statements.  Are you expecting us to guess as to what your program actually includes?  their are two valid signatures of `main()` Both of the valid signature have a return type of `int`,  So this signature: `main()` does not compile.  There is an unused parameter `t` in the function: `cofac()`.  in function: `det()` there is an unused variable `j` and  this line: `d=d+(t[1][i]*cofac(t,ord,1,i))` is missing the trailing `;`  please post the actual code

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*  2) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a single blank line.  3) separate functions by 2 or 3 blank lines (be consistent)

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful

Comment: variable names should indicate `content` or `usage`  (or better, both)

Comment: in the signature for function: `cofac()`, the parameter: `t[][]` is not used

Comment: the control flow of the posted program has function det() calling function: cofac(),  However, function: cofac() is calling function: det()   Probably not what you want.

Comment: Really sorry for the late comment...was busy with something.. I solved the problem by basically combining the determinant and cofactor functions.. I have posted the code in an answer if anybody is interested.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem by combining the determinant and cofactor function into one.. Here is the solution:

```
#include<stdio.h>
double det(float[10][10],int);
void main()
{
    int i,j,n;
    float a[10][10];
    printf("Enter order: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    if(n<=0)
    {
        printf("Please enter a positive value for order");
        goto end;
    }
    printf("Enter matrix:\n");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            scanf("%f",&a[i][j]);
        }
    }
    printf("The determinant is %f", det(a,n));
    end:;
}
double det(float m[10][10],int ord)
{
    int f=0,g=0,x,y,i,j,p=1;
    float t[10][10];
    double d=0;
    if(ord==1)
        d=m[0][0];
    else if(ord==2)
        d=(m[0][0]*m[1][1]-m[1][0]*m[0][1]);
    else if(ord>2)
    {
        for(x=0;x<ord;x++)
        {
            f=0;g=0;
            for(i=0;i<ord;i++)
            {
                for(j=0;j<ord;j++)
                {
                    if(i!=0 && j!=x)
                    {
                        t[f][g]=m[i][j];g++;
                    }
                }
                if(g==ord-1)
                {
                    g=0;f++;
                }
            }
            d=d+m[0][x]*p*det(t,ord-1);
            p=-1*p;
        }
    }
    return d;
}
```